# Вытащить элемент из базы xml и вставить программно в документ Word

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

```
XmlDocument odoc = new XmlDocument();
odoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");


        oWord = new Word.Application();

        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        Word.Paragraph oPara1;
        oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);

        oPara1.Range.Text = textBox4.Text;//вместо текстбокса надо каким-то образом передать элемент из базы xml  <nameAnketa></nameAnketa>
        oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;    
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        oPara1.Range.Text = textBox3.Text;//аналогично <vopros> </vopros>
        oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;   
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        oPara1.Range.Text = textBox1.Text;
        oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;   
        oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: Попробуй вот так  `odoc.GetElementsByTagName("nameAnketa").Item(0).InnerText` заместо textBox4.Text и далее по подобию

Comment: Отлично, то что надо! Только ввиду нулевого itema он у меня берет самые первые значения из базы, а их больше

Comment: Заместо нуля может быть любой другой индекс который вам надо. Да и в коде комментарий говорит об одном элементе: `надо каким-то образом передать элемент`. В каком виде вы собираетесь отобразить информацию с xml?

Comment: полагаю мне надо будет вставлять последние записанные элементы из базы и передать их в документ Word

Comment: Последний элемент будет под индексом `odoc.GetElementsByTagName("nameAnketa").Count -1`

Comment: Благодарю, вроде разобрался!

Comment: Оформил как ответ, отметьте как верный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтение xml файла:

```
XmlDocument odoc = new XmlDocument();
odoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
string value = odoc.GetElementsByTagName("nameAnketa").Item(0).InnerText;
```

Если требуется последний элемент в XML файле то:

```
int lastElement = odoc.GetElementsByTagName("nameAnketa").Count -1;
```